# Inserting a TextView text to SQLite upon a Button click

Tags: android, sqlite, button, textview

**Question**:  How do I pass a TextView information into a variable so when a button is clicked it will add that information to a created SQLite database called collections.

**Files left out (because I didn't think they related**: androidmanafest.xml, database.java (this was for populating the cards database), and cards.java (for setters getters).

**What it looks like**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jzAe.png)

**Main Activity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    SearchAdapter adapter;

    MaterialSearchBar materialSearchBar;
    List<String> suggestList = new ArrayList<>();

    Database database;

    //used for inserting card into collection database
    DB_Controller controller;
    TextView card_name, type, rarity, artist;

    Button addCollectionButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //This is all for the controller in order to pass each card into collection database
        controller = new DB_Controller(this,"collection.db",null,1);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_item);
        card_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.card_name);
        type = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.type);
        rarity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rarity);
        artist = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist);

        //functionality of button "ADD TO COLLECTION"
        addCollectionButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_collection);
        addCollectionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //when button clicked, insert into collection database
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String nameCard = card_name.getText().toString();
                String typeCard = type.getText().toString();
                String rarityCard = rarity.getText().toString();
                String artistCard = artist.getText().toString();
                //switch is used in case we need to add more buttons elsewhere in the app
                //switch(view.getId()){
                //    case R.id.button_collection:
                        //controller.insert_card("drl","drl", "drl", "drl", "drl");
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ADDED TO COLLECTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //confirm card was added
                        //break;
                //}
            }
        });

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //init View
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_search);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        materialSearchBar = (MaterialSearchBar)findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        //materialSearchBar.inflateMenu(R.layout.activity_main);
        //init DB
        database = new Database(this);

        //setup search bar
        //materialSearchBar.setHint("Search");
        //materialSearchBar.setCardViewElevation(10);
        loadSuggestList();

        //This is used when typing in search bar suggesting words like those that have been typed
        materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            // method for when user types in search bar, return suggested strings
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int after) {

                List<String> suggest = new ArrayList<>();
                for(String search : suggestList) {
                    if(search.toLowerCase().contains(materialSearchBar.getText().toLowerCase()))
                        suggest.add(search);
                }
                materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggest);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });


        //This is used when user has typed the word(s) needed to search and hits the search icon
        materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
                if(!enabled)
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
                startSearch(text.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

            }
        });

        //init Adapter default set all result
        //adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, database.getFriends());
        adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, database.getCards());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private void startSearch(String text) {
        //adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, database.getFriendByName(text));
        adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, database.getCardsByName(text));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    //for populating suggestion list when search bar has been activated
    private void loadSuggestList() {
        suggestList = database.getNames();
        materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggestList);
    }

}
```

**layout_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <!--Creation of overall look of searched results
        Main design tile for each searched result-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--default image for each tile-->
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

        <!--design tile within the main tile to display the information pulled from database-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!--information pulled from database design: NAME
            android:id="@+id/name"-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/card_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Eddy Lee"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <!--information pulled from database design: EMAIL
            android:id="@+id/email"-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/type"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:text="eddy@gmail.com"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <!--information pulled from database design: PHONE
            android:id="@+id/phone"-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rarity"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="(123)456-7890"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <!--information pulled from database design: ADDRESS
            android:id="@+id/address"-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/artist"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:text="123 Seseme Street"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_collection"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="Add to Collection"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.darrelbott.search.MainActivity">

    <com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
        app:mt_speechMode="false"
        app:mt_hint="Custom hint"
        app:mt_maxSuggestionsCount="10"
        app:mt_searchBarColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search_bar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_search"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**DB_Controller**:

```
public class DB_Controller extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TABLE_COLLECTION = "collection";
    private static final String COLUMN_COLLECTION_ACCOUNT = "account";
    private static final String COLUMN_COLLECTION_NAME = "card_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_COLLECTION_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String COLUMN_COLLECTION_RARITY = "rarity";
    private static final String COLUMN_COLLECTION_ARTIST = "artist";

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Context context;
    int version = 1;

    public DB_Controller(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, "collection.db", factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COLLECTION + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + COLUMN_COLLECTION_ACCOUNT + " TEXT, "
                + COLUMN_COLLECTION_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + COLUMN_COLLECTION_TYPE + " TEXT, "
                + COLUMN_COLLECTION_RARITY + " TEXT, "
                + COLUMN_COLLECTION_ARTIST + " TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        //sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS collection;");
        //onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void insert_card(String account, String card_name, String type, String rarity, String artist) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_COLLECTION_ACCOUNT,account);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_COLLECTION_NAME,card_name);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_COLLECTION_TYPE,type);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_COLLECTION_RARITY,rarity);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_COLLECTION_ARTIST,artist);

        db.insert(TABLE_COLLECTION,null,contentValues);


        //this.getWritableDatabase().insertOrThrow("collection.db","",contentValues);
    }
}
```

**Adapter** (which holds both SearchAdapter & SearchViewHolder):

```
    class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //public TextView name, address, email, phone;
    public TextView card_name, type, rarity, artist;

    public SearchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        card_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_name);
        type = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        rarity = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rarity);
        artist = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
    }
}

public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    //private List<Friend> friends;
    private List<Cards> cards;


    public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<Cards> cards /*List<Friend> friends*/ ) {
        this.context = context;
        //this.friends = friends;
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
        return new SearchViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    Button addCollectionButton;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        /*
        holder.name.setText(friends.get(position).getName());
        holder.address.setText(friends.get(position).getAddress());
        holder.email.setText(friends.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.phone.setText(friends.get(position).getPhone());
        */
        holder.card_name.setText(cards.get(position).getName());
        holder.type.setText(cards.get(position).getType());
        holder.rarity.setText(cards.get(position).getRarity());
        holder.artist.setText(cards.get(position).getArtist());

        /*
        //functionality of button "ADD TO COLLECTION"
        final DB_Controller controller = new DB_Controller(this,"collection.db",null,1);
        addCollectionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //when button clicked, insert into collection database
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //String card_name1 = card_name.setText(cards.get(position).getName());
                //switch is used in case we need to add more buttons elsewhere in the app
                //switch(view.getId()){
                //    case R.id.button_collection:
                controller.insert_card("drl","drl", "drl", "drl", "drl");
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ADDED TO COLLECTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //confirm card was added
                //break;
                //}
            }
        });
        */
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //return friends.size();
        return cards.size();
    }


}
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to add the `onClick()` method of your `addCollectionButton` Button to your  custom adapter class in the `onBindViewHolder()` method. The `button_collection` button in your `CardView` layout has nothing to do with the `main_activity` layout.

Comment: Is the fact that SearchAdapter isn't an Activity going to be a problem for this?

Comment: No--that is not going to be a problem. The `Adapter` of a `RecyclerView` will bind the data to the `ViewHolder` Views. In the `onBindViewHolder()` method you will reference the views of the `CardView`. That is where you need to handle the `onClick` events of your button--and where you add the rows to your database. It would be a good Idea to edit your post and add the `Adapter` class code.

Comment: Great observation, and I have added the Adapter classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the onClickListener inside the adapter where the button actually is. What you have done is have the listener in the main activity which is not correct. Put your listener in onBindViewHolder() and it should work if there is no issue in the sql code

Comment: Is that Sarcasm or did i actually help you?

Comment: Oh you had commented the same thing... My bad, i hadn't read that sorry

Answer (score 0):

As I commented earlier:  You need to add the `onClick()` method of your "addCollectionButton" `Button` to your custom adapter class in the `onBindViewHolder()` method. The "button_collection" `Button` in your `CardView` layout has nothing to do with the "main_activity" layout.

---

Try this code for your `Adapter`.

**Note:** I did this in a text editor, so there might be a couple of typos!

**Also Note**: I changed you "cards" `List` into an `ArrayList`--so you will need to compensate in you `Activity` code.

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = SearchAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;
    private final DB_Controller dbController;
    private ArrayList<Cards> cards;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView card_name, type, rarity, artist;
        public Button addCollectionButton;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            card_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_name);
            type = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            rarity = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rarity);
            artist = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            addCollectionButton = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_collection);
        }
    }


    public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cards> cards) {
        this.mContext = context;
        dbController = new DB_Controller(context,"collection.db",null,1);
        this.cards = cards;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Cards cardsData = cards.get(position);

        holder.card_name.setText(cardsData.getName());
        holder.type.setText(cardsData.getType());
        holder.rarity.setText(cardsData.getRarity());
        holder.artist.setText(cardsData.getArtist());

        holder.addCollectionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e(TAG, "on click " + position);

                String cardName = cardsData.getName();
                String cardType = cardsData.getType();
                String cardRarity = cardsData.getRarity();
                String cardArtist = cardsData.getArtist();

                // You will need to add the data as needed!
                dbController.insert_card("drl","drl", "drl", "drl", "drl");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "ADDED TO COLLECTION: " + cardName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //confirm card was added
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cards.size();
    }
}
```

----------
**Please let me know if you have any issues with the above code.**

Comment: holder.addCollectionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ------- addCollectionButton isn't being seen for some reason even though it is declared public

Comment: Alright...I obviously wrote that comment before actually looking.  However, here is the real problem:  
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference    
**@ line:**    
holder.addCollectionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   

**it also references:**  
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder> {

Comment: We can try two things. First, set the parameter `MyViewHolder ` in  `onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position)` from `@NonNull` to `final` like this `onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position)` and see if that helps. If it does NOT help remove `holder.addCollectionButton.setOnClickListener` and try `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener` instead. That should trigger the `onClick()` method if the `CardView` is clicked.

Comment: Changing to final did nothing.  Changing to itemView got rid of the error, however neither the Log.e msg or toast popup are showing, so to me that is telling me the button is "dead".  I've gotten null pointer errors before when my xml file wasn't linked correctly to my java file.  Is that maybe what is happening here?

Comment: Okay, so I was clicking the button for this.  When clicking the actual ListView it gives me the Toast message of it being added!  I will attempt to see if it has been added to the database (I don't see why not, but since I am running it on my phone I cannot see the database)

Comment: This works 100%.  Thank you Barns!  I upvoted this answer, but I am too new to the site to show it publicly.  So, this is my way of thanking you!  THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad I was able to help--I wish you success on your project!